# Ember data: How to specify usage of REST adapter in recent Ember version?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I simply want to change the data fetching froom a fixture adapter to a REST adapter.  I cannot find the correct syntax in the documentation ...  Whatever I try, no JSON call is executed against the REST interface.

can somebody help ?

ps. When I simply use a JQuery call (`return $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/articles.json');`), this works, but as mentioned above, I would like to use the Ember REST adapter ...

**My model:**

```
App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**My fixures adapter:**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

**My REST adapter (NOT WORKING)**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RestAdapter.create({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000'
  })
});
```

**My route**

```
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    App.Article.find();
    //return $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/articles.json');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the class name wrong, it needs to be `DS.RESTAdapter` instead of `DS.RestAdapter`

Try this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000'
  })
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks. This was indeed the problem.  My JSON call is now executed, but I have now problems with the result .... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023998/