# Ember data: Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple model and use the RESTadapter to get the data.  The JSON request is executed, but then I receive the following error: "Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it"

Any idea what the reason is ?

**Model:**

```
App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**JSON Response of request articles.json:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title 2"
  }
]
```

I think the reason is the format of the response ...  I have already changed my response to include "article", but stil the same problem.

```
[
  {
    "article": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Title 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "article": {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Title 2"
    }
  }
]
```

Where can I find a good documentation on how the JSOn request and response should be formatted for use with the RESTadapter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON you are looking for should have a root element

```
{"articles": [ 
  { 
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title 2"
   }
  ]
}
```

You can find documentation in the [Ember Docs RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) or at the [JSONapi project](http://jsonapi.org/format/)

Comment: Thanks.  Still does not work after including root element "article" - same error. Could the problem be the pluralisation ?  I return a list of articles which need to be put in "article".  Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Totally article needs to be articles, my mistake I will edit the answer.

Comment: This is indeed the correct structure. ANy idea where I can find documentation about the expected Ember JSON structure ?  Many thanks. Marc

Comment: I added a couple of links to documentation. I hope that it is helpful.

Comment: Thx for the documentation ! Marc

Answer (score 2):

@kiwiupover was 98% right, when having multiple records it should be pluralized to `articles`:

```
{"articles": [
     { 
       "id": 1,
       "title": "Title 1"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "title": "Title 2"
     }
]}
```

Comment: Indeed, using articles, it works.  Any idea where I can find documentation about JSON structure for use with Ember data (thinking about one to many data structures, etc.) ... Thanks

Comment: Thanks heaps for the 98% I have fixed the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the server, it's pretty easy to modify the adapter. For the "GET" requests, you'll need to override `find` and `findAll` within your adapter:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    find: function(store, type, id) {
      var root = this.rootForType(type), adapter = this;

      return this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), "GET").
      then(function(json){
        var updatedJSON = {};
        updatedJSON[root] = json;
        adapter.didFindRecord(store, type, {article: json}, id);
      }).then(null, DS.rejectionHandler);
    },

    findAll: function(store, type, since) {
      var root, adapter;

      root = this.rootForType(type);
      adapter = this;

      var resourceName = this.pluralize(root);

      return this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "GET",{
        data: this.sinceQuery(since)
      }).then(function(json) {
        var updatedJSON = {};
        updatedJSON[resourceName] = json;
        adapter.didFindAll(store, type, updatedJSON);
      }).then(null, DS.rejectionHandler);
    }
  })
});
```

At the moment, these functions live in the source code [here in rest_adapter.js](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4764b5d70c41c133edcbd1822bc587483c39e180/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L366).

The difference here is where `updatedJSON` is defined in each of the functions. It takes the json from the server and constructs a new object with (hopefully) the correct key you need.

Comment: So it looks as if this method is no long a working example would you be willing to show how this would work with ember data 1.0?

Comment: To be honest, I stopped trying to work with Ember when I realized how quickly things changed and broke what used to work.