# Ember Data 1.0 with none standard json

Tags: json, github, ember.js, ember-data

I'm looking to use json from Github's issues api with Ember Data.

The problem is that the return json is not formatted the way ember data wants it to be. 
Github returns data as such.

```
[ 
  {id: 0, title: 'test'},
  {id: 1, title: "ect.."}
]
```

Where as Ember Data's RestAdapter expects it to be like:

```
{ issues: [ 
  {id: 0, title: 'test'},
  {id: 1, title: "ect.."}
] }
```

I assume based on some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023998/ember-data-your-server-returned-a-hash-with-the-key-0-but-you-have-no-mapping-f/18523699#18523699) that I need to override the Find and FindAll methods for the DS.RestAdapter

```
MyApp.Issue = DS.Model.extend({ ... });

MyApp.IssueAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js',

  find: function(store, type, id) {
    ...
  },

  findAll: function(store, type since) {
    ...
  },

}
```

The problem is in the example if found there are a few out of data methods and it also does not explain how I can pass a array with out an key of "issues"

To be honest I'm really a complete noob to all this and most of this js is over my head but I feel like I'm close to figuring this out. Let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Others can try to tackle how to do this with EmberData; there are definiltely ways to customize EmberData with custom adapters, serializers, etc. Personally I would choose to avoid using EmberData, as even its own github says it's not production ready. Rather than adapting EmberData to suit your needs, use custom ajax calls. Check out this guide from a co-founder of Discourse: http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html